# Recursive Binary search for sqrt

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

int binarySearch(long long int N,int start,int end, int& num){

    

    long long int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
    //cout<<"Start: "<<start << " End: " <<  end<<" Mid: "<<mid<<endl;
    long long int square = mid*mid;
    if(start>end){
        return num;
    }
    
    if(square<=N){
        num = mid;
        start = mid+1;
    }else{
        end = mid-1;
    }

    binarySearch(N,start,end,num);

    return num;

}


int sqrtN(long long int N)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = N;

    int sqrt = 0;

    binarySearch(N, start, end, sqrt);

    return sqrt;
}
```

I was writing a code to find square root using recursive binary search.
In this code of mine it is failing for very large numbers can anyone help me in fixing this

Comment: How large is very large? Please show a [mre] including, inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs

Comment: I was doing this question on : -    https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/square-root_893351?source=youtube&campaign=love_babbar_codestudio2&utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=love_babbar_codestudio2&leftPanelTab=0

and it only passes 9/11 test cases

Comment: That link is good context to have, but links to third-party sites will often be broken in a few years so you should put all the things Alan requested in your question.

Comment: Note that anything with `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in it makes it impossible for many users to even *attempt* to reproduce your issues, or use your code. **Just stop doing that!**

Answer (score 0):

This calculation

```cpp
long long int square = mid*mid;
```

may cause integer overflows.

The condition

```cpp
square<=N
```

should be:

```cpp
(mid == 0 || mid <= LLONG_MAX / mid) && square<=N
```